# How to track how many times a UIButton has been pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I need to know how many times a button in my program has been pressed. I tried making a category of `UIButton` and adding properties to it so that each time a button is pressed I would say `sender.someproperty++;` but the compiler complains when I add properties to a category.

Any way I can track this? I wish every object in Xcode had a random `unassigned integer property` that you could randomly assign it different values to keep track of each object

the first time I press the button, I want something to happen, the second time, I want something else to happen, the third time, I want something else to happen, and then the fourth time I want it to default so its like I'm pressing it the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing UIButton is definitely dangerous, because UIButton not a single class but a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html).  I highly recommend not doing this.  According to Apple:

> The class cluster architecture involves a trade-off between simplicity and extensibility: Having a few public classes stand in for a multitude of private ones makes it easier to learn and use the classes in a framework but somewhat harder to create subclasses within any of the clusters.
>
> A new class that you create within a class cluster must:
>
> -Be a subclass of the cluster’s abstract superclass
>
> -Declare its own storage
>
> -Override the superclass’s primitive methods

Instead of adding a property to the category, you can use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) and add getter and setter methods to the category to simulate a property on the button.

Comment: thanks, but i never subclassed it i just used the tag property, it works great!

Answer (score 2):

What youre going to want to do is to create a buttonPressedCounter property in the view controller of the view that the button is in, and keep track of it that way.

As for the changing functionality, define it for buttonPressedCounter = 0, 1, and 2, and after that either reset the counter in your behavior for buttonPressedCounter = 2, or your check should be based on buttonPressedCounter % 3.

**EDITED FOR COMMENTS:**
What you can also do, I think, is to create a new class that extends UIButton, and declare a counter property inside of it. This should work for you, and may fit your tastes better than an array of counter variables.

Might look something like this,

```
@interface UIButtonCountable : UIButton
{
    int _clickCounter;
}

@property (nonatomic) int clickCounter;

@end
```

Another option again, is to not use a UIButton, but to use either a slider with 3 possible values, or segmented control, though I have little to no experience with either of those.

Comment: yea i can make a property in my vc but that won't solve the problem, because i have 48 buttons, and each one i want to change the buttonPressedCounter individually, i don't want to press one button, have the counter go to 1, then press a different one, and the counter go to 2. I want to be able to press one button, have that button's counter go to 1, then when i press another button, that button's counter goes to 1. Thats why i wanted to change a property of sender

Comment: You dont have to create an IBOutlet for each button you want pressed, youd just have to create 48 properties. In your situation though I would instead create and array of 48 integers, and then if, say, button 25 is pressed you just reference buttonPressedCounterArray[24] and increment that value. Now the question is, are you going to have 48 times 3 unique actions happening, or still only 3 unique actions?

Comment: Check my answer again, Ive edited in another option that I think would work the best for you.

Comment: I was just hoping that their was a built in property in UIButton i could use, like i know there is a selected state in UIButton, but this would only let me toggle selected on and off, I wouldn't have 3 options just 2 i think

Comment: Why do you think it might be dangerous? Honestly that sounds like the most direct solution to your problem. As for something that is built into the UIButton class, I don't know of anything, though I can double check the class reference really quick. EDIT: Yea I'm not seeing it anything that might help you that is built in.

Comment: Subclassing a UIButton really is dangerous.  Don't do it unless you understand class clusters and are sure you know what you're doing.  See my answer below for more information.